# Вывод числительного в падеже

Tags: c++, c

Нужно ввести число, указать падеж, вывести число в нужном падеже.(до одной тысячи)

---

Перевести в строку в им. падеже: Есть.
Что еще:
Например:

```
...
sprintf(buf, "%s%s", Morph(ten[n / 10],T)), Morph(one[n % 10],T));
...
```

#### Что происходит:

берется из массива строка, передается в функцию  `Morph(const char *str, Case T)`
`Case` - перечисление, которое указывает падеж.
Какой третий параметр добавить, чтобы перегрузить функцию??
Т.е чтобы оставить то же название, но добавить какой-то третий параметр, в зависимости от которого, вызывалась бы одна из 5 функций.(под десятки, сотни, и тд)
Можно конечно просто разные имена поставить. 
Ну или не перегружать а внутри if[ы] пихать, и так запутаюсь..

Ну и самый главный вопрос, каким образом мне теперь делать перевод?? Понимаю что нужно использовать strcat, ну и на этом всё :(

Или проще будет еще 20 массивов дописать, под остальные падежи??

Писать в принципе ничего не прошу, хотя бы подсказать идейно.

Спасибо!

Актуально..

Comment: Я бы посмотрел в формулы и техники, которые применяются в пакете `gettext`. Это библиотека поддержки i18n в *nix системах. Поскольку языки отличаются, то в переводимых строках необходимо как раз учитывать варианты числительных (в русском 3, в английском 2, помимо специальных, типа *второй*). Это только часть вашей задачи, но может натолкнёт на какие-то мыслию

Comment: Увы и ах, пришлось прописывать руками массивы..Т.к. был уже дедлайн, а ничего нового я сам не придумал. В принципе, прописал 6 падежей чисел от 1 до 19, 20, 30.. 100, .. 900
А потом уже объединял то что надо. Удовольствие сомнительное, но что поделать.

Comment: Н-да... Тесты на творительном падеже проходит все? (Ну и так, на будущее, в русском 9 падежей, только в школе об этом не говорят).

Comment: Возможно, я ведь не на лингвиста учусь.
Да и принимающий вряд ли знал о существовании 9 падежей :)
Ну, с большего - да, может и есть какие косяки, все варианты само собой не проверял, но вроде как всё что проверял я и принимающий - выдавало как нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что нет смысла делать перегрузку. Не стоит привязываться к разрядности чисел из соображений расширения программы (если вдруг вам нужно будет сделать тоже самое, только до миллиона).
Вам нужно написать функцию, определяющую корень введенного слова, после чего к корню подставить соответствующее окончание, для нужного падежа.

---

Например:
Вам передается слово "Десять":

- И: Десять
- Р: Десяти
- Д: Десяти
- В: Десять
- Т: Десятью
- П: Десяти

Во всех формах слова присутствует неизменяемая часть "Десят". Важно выделить эту чать, окончание добавить в зависимости от падежа.

Comment: По поводу функций понял, в данном примере может и нет смысла, а в целом, каким образом это можно сделать? (изменить типы параметров, их количество, то что знаю) Единственное что пришло в голову, третьем параметров, в зависимости от разрядности числа, передавать разный тип, т.е для десяток - тип int, для сотен -
 double) ну и явно их передавать вызывая функции:
По поводу корня, можете чуть подробнее? Было бы неплохо на примере каком-нибудь.(в виде текста)

Comment: Ну, так то в жизни, оно понятно. но у меня ведь есть только три массива в И.П.
 char *one[] = { "","один ","два ","три ","четыре ","пять ","шесть ","семь ","восемь ","девять ",
  "десять ","одиннадцать ","двенадцать ","тринадцать ","четырнадцать ","пятнадцать ",
  "шестнадцать ","семнадцать ","восемнадцать ","девятнадцать " };
 char *ten[] = { "","", "двадцать ", "тридцать ", "сорок ", "пятьдесят ", "шестьдесят ", "семьдесят ",
  "восемьдесят ", "девяносто " };
... (остальное не вмещается)
Берется какой-то один элемент из массива, как в нем выделить корень?

Comment: восемьдесят восьмидесяти восемьюдесятью...

Comment: `одной тысячей / одной тысячью двумястами`  Короче, все не так просто, как кажется на первый взгляд